# What's the difference between File.open() with and without a block?

Tags: ruby, file, file-io

I have 2 questions :
1 - I don't understand meaning of thing that , this code return :

```
File.open("a.txt") do |i|
  puts i
end
```

please explain me.

2 - and please explain me what is the difference between that code and below
code :

```
File.open("a.txt").each do |i|
  puts i
end
```

thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With:

```
File.open( "some_file.txt" ) do |file|
  puts file.read
end
```

The open method calls your block with a **File** instance and cleans up the file reference once your block returns, closing and flushing the file as needed, so your application does not leak file handlers, which is awesome as we usually forget to close files or do not take into account that file handling might yield exceptions.

When you do it like this:

```
file = File.open("some_file.txt")
puts file.read
```

The open method gives you the **File** instance but now you are responsible for cleaning up the mess and closing the file when you don't need it anymore. So, if you're doing it like this, you should possibly set the file into a begin/rescue block and add an ensure clause closing the file if anything goes wrong.

Unless you have a very specific need, you should never use this second version, the first version is simpler and safer and you don't have to care about closing/cleaning up whatever you did to the file.

Comment: You forget to close file in your second example :D

Answer (score 2):

You can generally enter something as simple as this right in the console and get an immediate answer.

So for a file a.txt with contents:

```
one
two
three
```

Your code will do this:

```
[johnmartirano@mbp]$ irb
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :007 > File.open("a.txt") do |i|
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :008 >     puts "a.txt:"+i.to_s
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :009?>   end
a.txt:#<File:0x000001010e7ae8>
 => nil 
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :010 > File.open("a.txt").each do |i|
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :011 >     puts "a.txt:"+i.to_s
ruby-1.9.2-p180 :012?>   end
a.txt:one
a.txt:two
a.txt:three
 => #<File:a.txt>
```

So the first one prints the File object reference/address.

The 2nd one iterates through the lines in the file and prints each one.

Hope that helps